# Why am i paying gas to test a smart contract on hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Im building a trading bot with solidity and i started testing it, when i test the script i use this command: `yarn hardhat test --network goerli` i add the `--network goerli` because  in my scripts there are addresses of tokens and i need to use the goerli network to test them. Doing that i pay a lot of gas in goerli eth and i was wondering if there was a way to test the contract on the goerli network without paying gas fees to test it.
The code of the full contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

interface Structs {
    struct Val {
        uint256 value;
    }

    enum ActionType {
        Deposit, // supply tokens
        Withdraw, // borrow tokens
        Transfer, // transfer balance between accounts
        Buy, // buy an amount of some token (externally)
        Sell, // sell an amount of some token (externally)
        Trade, // trade tokens against another account
        Liquidate, // liquidate an undercollateralized or expiring account
        Vaporize, // use excess tokens to zero-out a completely negative account
        Call // send arbitrary data to an address
    }

    enum AssetDenomination {
        Wei // the amount is denominated in wei
    }

    enum AssetReference {
        Delta // the amount is given as a delta from the current value
    }

    struct AssetAmount {
        bool sign; // true if positive
        AssetDenomination denomination;
        AssetReference ref;
        uint256 value;
    }

    struct ActionArgs {
        ActionType actionType;
        uint256 accountId;
        AssetAmount amount;
        uint256 primaryMarketId;
        uint256 secondaryMarketId;
        address otherAddress;
        uint256 otherAccountId;
        bytes data;
    }

    struct Info {
        address owner; // The address that owns the account
        uint256 number; // A nonce that allows a single address to control many accounts
    }

    struct Wei {
        bool sign; // true if positive
        uint256 value;
    }
}

abstract contract DyDxPool is Structs {
    function getAccountWei(Info memory account, uint256 marketId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        returns (Wei memory);

    function operate(Info[] memory, ActionArgs[] memory) public virtual;
}

contract DyDxFlashLoan is Structs {
    DyDxPool pool = DyDxPool(0x1E0447b19BB6EcFdAe1e4AE1694b0C3659614e4e);

    address public WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    mapping(address => uint256) public currencies;

    constructor() {
        currencies[WETH] = 1;
    }

    modifier onlyPool() {
        require(
            msg.sender == address(pool),
            "FlashLoan: could be called by DyDx pool only"
        );
        _;
    }

    function tokenToMarketId(address token) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 marketId = currencies[token];
        require(marketId != 0, "FlashLoan: Unsupported token");
        return marketId - 1;
    }

    // the DyDx will call `callFunction(address sender, Info memory accountInfo, bytes memory data) public` after during `operate` call
    function flashloan(
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes memory data
    ) internal {
        IERC20(token).approve(address(pool), amount + 1);
        Info[] memory infos = new Info[](1);
        ActionArgs[] memory args = new ActionArgs[](3);

        infos[0] = Info(address(this), 0);

        AssetAmount memory wamt = AssetAmount(
            false,
            AssetDenomination.Wei,
            AssetReference.Delta,
            amount
        );
        ActionArgs memory withdraw;
        withdraw.actionType = ActionType.Withdraw;
        withdraw.accountId = 0;
        withdraw.amount = wamt;
        withdraw.primaryMarketId = tokenToMarketId(token);
        withdraw.otherAddress = address(this);

        args[0] = withdraw;

        ActionArgs memory call;
        call.actionType = ActionType.Call;
        call.accountId = 0;
        call.otherAddress = address(this);
        call.data = data;

        args[1] = call;

        ActionArgs memory deposit;
        AssetAmount memory damt = AssetAmount(
            true,
            AssetDenomination.Wei,
            AssetReference.Delta,
            amount + 1
        );
        deposit.actionType = ActionType.Deposit;
        deposit.accountId = 0;
        deposit.amount = damt;
        deposit.primaryMarketId = tokenToMarketId(token);
        deposit.otherAddress = address(this);

        args[2] = deposit;

        pool.operate(infos, args);
    }
}

contract Arbitrage is DyDxFlashLoan {
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uRouter;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable sRouter;

    address public owner;

    constructor(address _uRouter, address _sRouter) payable {
        uRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uRouter);
        sRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sRouter);
        owner = msg.sender;
        (bool success, ) = WETH.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "fail to get weth");
    }

    function executeTrade(
        address _tokenA,
        address _tokenB,
        uint _tokensFromFlashLoan,
        bool _startOnUniswap
    ) external {
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(_tokenA);
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            _startOnUniswap,
            _tokenA,
            _tokenB,
            _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            balanceBefore
        );
        flashloan(_tokenA, _tokensFromFlashLoan, data);
    }

    function callFunction(
        address,
        Info calldata,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external onlyPool {
        (
            bool _startOnUniswap,
            address _tokenA,
            address _tokenB,
            uint256 _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            uint256 balanceBefore
        ) = abi.decode(data, (bool, address, address, uint256, uint256));
        uint balanceAfter = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));

        require(
            balanceAfter - balanceBefore == _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            "Didn't receive flash loan"
        );

        address[] memory tokens;
        if (_startOnUniswap == true) {
            tokens[0] = _tokenA;
            tokens[1] = _tokenB;

            swapOnUniswap(_tokensFromFlashLoan, 10, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnSushiswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                10,
                tokens
            );
        } else {
            tokens[0] = _tokenA;
            tokens[1] = _tokenB;

            swapOnSushiswap(_tokensFromFlashLoan, 10, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnUniswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                10,
                tokens
            );
        }
    }

    function swapOnUniswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        // swapExactTokensForTokes
        // mettiamo dentro un input token e riceviamo un output token
        // controllare se il token è effetivamente un token
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(uRouter), _amountIn),
            "Uniswap failed the approval"
        );

        // swappiamo i token e li riceve lo smart contract
        uint[] memory amounts = uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );
        require(
            amounts[1] == IERC20(_path[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
            "Didn't receive tokens from swap"
        );
    }

    function swapOnSushiswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(sRouter), _amountIn),
            "Sushiswap failed the approval"
        );

        uint[] memory amounts = uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );

        require(
            amounts[1] == IERC20(_path[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
            "Didn't receive tokens from swap"
        );
    }
}
```

This is the code of the test script (its not complete yet):

```
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat");
const { provider } = require("../utils/config");
const hre = require("hardhat");
require("dotenv").config();

let arbitrageFactory, arbitrageContract;
const uRouterAddress = process.env.MAINNET_AND_GOERLI_UNISWAP_ROUTERV2_ADDRESS;
const sRouterAddress = process.env.GOERLI_SUSHISWAP_ROUTERV2_ADDRESS;
const tokenA = process.env.TOKEN_WETH_TESTNET;
const tokenB = process.env.TOKEN_COMPOUND_TESTNET;

describe("Arbitrage", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    arbitrageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Arbitrage");

    arbitrageContract = await arbitrageFactory.deploy(
      uRouterAddress,
      sRouterAddress,
      { value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("0.00000000000000001") }
    );
    senderAddress = await arbitrageContract.signer.address;
    contractAddress = arbitrageContract.address;
  });

  describe("executeTrade", async () => {
    let trade, balanceBefore, balanceAfter;
    const flashAmount = 10;
    const options = { gasLimit: 3000000 };

    beforeEach(async () => {
      balanceBefore = await provider.getBalance(contractAddress);
      trade = await arbitrageContract.executeTrade(
        tokenA,
        tokenB,
        flashAmount,
        false,
        options
      );
      balanceAfter = await provider.getBalance(contractAddress);
    });

    it("Should verify that the flashloan was received correctly", async () => {
      expect(balanceAfter - balanceBefore, flashAmount);
    });
  });
});
```

if you have any suggestion please help me i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware if Goerli could be forked, but if a local copy of mainnet is fine for you then you can fork the mainnet locally in hardhat. You can find more info here https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks
And in your test script why are you deploying the contract over and over again?